# Number of distinct solutions of $f(f(x))=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f(x)=x^3-3x+1.$ Then what is the number of different real solutions of the

equation $f(f(x))=0$?

$f(x)$ has three roots and $f(f(x))$ will be 0 when value of $f(x)$ is equal to its root. But this approach is turning out to be tedious as finding exact values of roots of $f(x)$ is not possible Could someone suggest a better approach?

Comment: Is the answer is $7$ Real solution.

Comment: @juantheron how did you get $7$? It could have been nine, for example.

Comment: You can see it with at [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E3-3x%2B1)%5E3-3(x%5E3-3x%2B1)%2B1+%3D+0), but that's not a proof.

Comment: As $x$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, $f(x)$ rises from $-\infty$ to $3$, then goes back down to $-1$, then goes up to $\infty$. There is one root in $(-\infty,-1]$ and two in $[-1,3]$. So on the way up $f(x)$ crosses all three roots, hits two again on the way down, and the same two on the way up again. That makes a total of seven.

Answer (score 2):

$$f(x)=x^3 -3x+1$$

$$f'(x)=3x^2-3$$

So the maximum is at $(-1,3)$ , minimum at $(1,-1)$

Thus $f(x)$ has $3$ real root.

Now in order for $f(f(x))=0$, $f(x)$ must be equal to one of its roots.

So it is really asking how many roots does each $f(x)=k$ have, where $k$ is a root of $f(x)$.

As observed from the calculation above, the minimum is at $y=-1$ and the maximum is at $y=3$. So if $f(x)>3$ or $f(x)<-1$, there is only one root. Whereas if $f(x)$ equals $-1$ or $3$, there are two distinct roots. If $-1<f(x)<3$, there are three distinct roots.

Answer (score 1):

First observe that the roots $\alpha, \beta,\gamma$ satisfies  $-2<\alpha<-1<\beta<1<\gamma<2$. (Thust an application of IVT.)
Then, the roots of the given equation are precisely the roots of $f(x)=\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. Using the fact that the local minimum and maximum of $f$ appears at $x=\pm1$, you can tell how many roots are there for each three equations using the plot of the function and the range of $\alpha,\beta,$ and $\gamma$.

Comment: The least root of $f(f(x))$ is about $-2.09 < -2$.

Comment: The 'root' in the first line is for the roots for $f(x)$. Sorry for the ambiguity.